# Next-Auth with LinkedIn throws me error [next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] jwks_uri must be configured on the issuer jwks_uri must be configured

Tags: next.js, linkedin-api, next.js13, next-auth

I'm trying to use Next-Auth with LinkedIn and I'm getting this error.

`[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]  https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error jwks_uri must be configured on the issuer { error: TypeError: jwks_uri must be configured on the issuer at assertIssuerConfiguration`

The login process is going perfectly. But after log into the LinkedIn it will not return to me User Data. And also user will not showing as log in. Pararrely I'm using Google sign-in and it works perfect. The problem comming up with the LinkedIn. Someone can solve this error it would be really helpfull.

I tried bellow code.

```
    LinkedInProvider({
      clientId: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      authorization: {
        params: { scope: 'openid profile email' },
      },
      issuer: 'https://www.linkedin.com',
      jwks_endpoint: 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/openid/jwks',
      profile(profile, tokens) {
        const defaultImage =
          'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png';
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture ?? defaultImage,
        };
      },
    }),
```

Comment: I solved this issue by uninstalling the Next-Auth from the project and installing the @next-auth/prisma-adapter. Also, I have upgraded the @prisma/client and Prisma to the latest versions. And make sure that @prisma/client and Prisma have the same versions. With these changes and the above code LinkedIn auth is working fine in NextJS, Next-Auth, and Prisma.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue try this way

```
  LinkedInProvider({
      clientId: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
      client: { token_endpoint_auth_method: "client_secret_post" },
      scope: "r_liteprofile r_emailaddress",
      issuer: "https://www.linkedin.com",
      userinfo: {
        url: "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo",
      },
      tokenUri: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
      wellKnown:
        "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      authorization: {
        url: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
        params: {
          scope: "profile email openid",
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code",
        },
      },
     
      token: {
        url: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
      },
      jwks_endpoint: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/openid/jwks",
      async profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          firstname: profile.given_name,
          lastname: profile.family_name,
          email: profile.email,
        };
      },
    }),
```